# Reinstalling Windows 7 and Re-attach Users directory

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I have followed the many guides on how to separate my OS from my data files.  I have Windows 7 installed on C: and my "Users" directory installed on D: with a Junction from C:\Users -> D:\Users.  My question is, when I go to format and re-install Windows 7 on C:, how do I setup the same users with the permissions to be correct when I re-create the Junction?  Does the usernames just have to match (I wouldn't think so), do the computer names also have to match, or what else?

Thanks in advance.